# Haskell task - what is the solution

Tags: haskell

I need some help with a problem in Haskell.

I want to create a function that would take three arguments--the first argument would be a character representing an arithmetic operation such as `'+', '-', '*', '/'`, with the next two arguments lists of numbers, and this function should return a list of numbers such that given the arguments

```
'-' [3,4,7] [-4,6,6]
```

it would return

```
[7,-2,1]
```

but I don't know how to get started.

Also, how could one compute the minimum element of the resulting list?

Comment: Why is the first element of your result list `-1` and not `7` (`3 - (-4)`)? Also what do you mean the result needs to be the minimum? The minimum of what? Do you mean you just want to return the minimum of the list and not the whole list?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake .. the result is [7,-2,1]. And yes, I want the minimum of the list, whatever that means. I tried something <br />
func1 op l1 l2 = [a op b | a <- l1, b <- l2] <br />
but it doesn't work and I don't know how to parse the string '-' to operator MINUS.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want but here I input (-) .. is it possible to works with '-'

Comment: You can use `(case '-' of { '+' -> (+); '-' -> (-); '*' -> ... })` to "convert" between the char representation and numerical operators.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the functions

`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`

and

`minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`.

You should be able to build your desired function with these.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
f opStr x y = zipWith op x y where
    op = case opStr of
        '+' -> (+)
        '-' -> (-)
        '*' -> (*)
        '/' -> (/)
```

Or even shorter, you can replace the first line by;

```
f opStr = zipWith op where
```